# Excel macro to replace cells content from a 2 columns lookup

Tags: excel, macros, lookup, vba

In a worksheet, Sheet1, I need to go through column A and look for any value of Sheet2 col. A and replace the string found by Sheet2 col. B value.

For example if I have "go to http://google.com every day" somewhere in Sheet1.A and "google" in Sheet2.A234, I need to replace the original string by Sheet2.B234 value ("stackoverflow") to get "go to http://stackoverflow.com every day" into the original cell or in a new column.
No change if nothing is found.

I don't know much about vba, I only slightly modified some code found here and there. I know how to make a formula to do this but I can get any loop/range working in this case.

Any help appreciated :)

Fred

YowE3K works great, less elegant but working too:

```
Sub remplace()

Dim myInput As String, myTest As String, myReplacement As String

For i = 1 To 8 'for 10 rows of data in Sheet2
    For j = 1 To 4 'for 5 rows of data in Sheet1

        myInput = Sheets("Sheet3").Cells(j, 1).Value
        myTest = Sheets("Sheet4").Cells(i, 1).Value
        myReplacement = Sheets("Sheet4").Cells(i, 2).Value

        resultText = Replace(myInput, myTest, myReplacement)

        Sheets("Sheet3").Cells(j, 1).Value = resultText

    Next j
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: You might consider showing your formula, probably would help others understand what you're doing and make it easier for them to assist you :)

Answer (score 1):

The following code should do what you want, but may not be terribly efficient if you have large numbers of rows in either Sheet1 or Sheet2.  ("large" probably means > 1000)

```
Sub ReplaceValues
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim rows1 As Long
    Dim rows2 As Long

    Dim row1 As Long
    Dim row2 As Long

    Set ws1 = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set ws2 = Worksheets("Sheet2")

    rows1 = ws1.Range("A" & ws1.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    rows2 = ws2.Range("A" & ws2.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For row1 = 1 To rows1
        For row2 = 1 To rows2
            ws1.Cells(row1, 1).Value = Replace(ws1.Cells(row1, 1).Value, _
                                               ws2.Cells(row2, 1).Value, _
                                               ws2.Cells(row2, 2).Value)
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

the below code will do the job

```
Sub foo()

For i = 1 To 10 'for 10 rows of data in Sheet2
    For j = 1 To 5 'for 5 rows of data in Sheet1
        If Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(i, 1).Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(j, 1).Value Then
            Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(j, 1).Value = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(i, 2).Value
        End If
    Next j
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Thomas, thanks for your help, I have just adapted your code to perform a Replace because my values are not "equals" and need partial replacement. The result above ;)

Comment: Glad to know that you found the solution